# Angular upgrade from version 8 to 11 made fonts blurred

Tags: angular, fonts, angular-upgrade

After upgrading `Angular` from version 8 to 11, fonts are looking different, they are blurred. Any ideas on what can I do/check to make them look the same as they were before? Any help would be appreciated. When I run the app locally, it looks better than in the deployment environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be hit by something similar to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19350).
There is a new optimization for fonts - external font definitions are inlined as part of the production build. According to the bug above, it might not work in some cases.
Try disabling the fonts inlining optimization in angular.json - https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#fonts-optimization-options